# Letting the User Assign List Names

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to  write a program that will keep track of a student's grades in all of his courses. The student adds the course and also adds the different segments of the course and how they are weighted, which is why I was planning on using a dictionary. I've been using an input function to allow the user to enter the name of each segment. The dictionary might look like this: 
    {"homework": .2, "tests": .8} 
Each course might have different weightings or even a different number of segments. So to keep track of the grades I want to make a homework list and a tests list that the student can enter his grades into. Therefore, I want what the user enters to be the name of the list that keeps track of the grades, so I can store the students grades in a list. Thoughts? Or can you think of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures can be nested.

```
{'mylist': [], 'awesomedict': {}}
```

Comment: I would add that the nested data structures can be manipulated just like they would if they were stored in seperate variables:  so gradedict['mylist'].append(89) and gradedict['awesomedict']['anewkey]='mykey' are valid